# Как получить доли от числа в javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Например есть число 4.6737464

Нужно получить 0.6737464

Тоесть все тоже кроме целого числа.

Может есть какой то метод?

Comment: Можно взять остаток от деления на 1: `let fract = 4.567 % 1;`

Comment: А как быть с 99999999 в конце?

Comment: Округлил до целого и вычел    (4 - 4.6737464), возможно есть более изящный способ?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan в этом нет особой проблемы, если она есть то необходимо с ходу использовать длинную арифметику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let num = 4.6737464
let countafterdot = num.toString().split('.')[1].length

let result = parseFloat(num - parseInt(num)).toFixed(countafterdot)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Для `num = 0.000000123` результат будет неожиданным. А для `num = 0.0000001` - ещё более неожиданным. :)

Answer (score 2):

Крайне странный способ, зато не будет `00000000001` на конце

```
let a = 123.456789;
let b = Number(`${a}`.replace(/\d+\./, '0.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Upd:
Чтобы учесть точность:

```
let a = 4.6737464;
let decimalPlaces = a.toString().split('.')[1].length; // количество знаков после запятой в исходном числе
let b = a - parseInt(a);
alert(b.toFixed(decimalPlaces));
```

Comment: На выходе будет - 0.6737463999999997

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan изменил код.

Answer (score 0):

```
const os = require('os');

function upTime() {
  let sec = os.uptime; //время работы компа в секундах
  calcToH();

  function calcToH() {
    let hour = Math.floor(sec / 60) / 60;
    let hourParse = Math.floor(hour * 10 / 10)
    let min = Math.floor((hour - hourParse) * 60) * 10 / 10
    console.log(hourParse + ' Часов ' + min + ' Минут');
  }
}

upTime();
```